# Terminology for $f(tx) \leq tf(x)$ when $0\leq t \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, terminology

That $f(tx) \leq tf(x)$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$ is a famous property of convex functions, often used, for example, in the proof that [convex functions are superadditive on the positive reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable).

***Edit***: "A famous property of convex functions **such that $f(0) \geq 0$**", as the Wikipedia article mentions, sorry for not including that extra condition in my original post.

In economics, properties like $[f(tx) \le tf(x)$ for $0\le t \le 1]$ are often discussed in terms of "returns to scale".

**My question** is, in mathematics, is there a common name for the property $[f(tx) \le tf(x)$ for $0\le t \le 1]$?

Comment: Remark: This is like a weaker version of convexity where the only secant lines that are required to lie above the graph are the ones through $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a **starshaped** function, see definition 2 in [1].

*Reference*:

[[1] A. M. Bruckner and E. Ostrow, "Some Function Classes Related to
the Class of Convex Functions", 1962.](https://msp.org/pjm/1962/12-4/pjm-v12-n4-p05-p.pdf)

Comment: Here are some other references that use the same terminology: https://sciendo.com/pdf/10.1515/mjpaa-2017-0012, http://journalcam.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/100207.pdf, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2239585?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents.

Comment: @FZS Yes, there are more.

Answer (score 0):

There are convex functions that do not satisfy this property:

The functions $f(x)=x^2+a$ satisfy the property
$$\tag{1}
f(tx)\le tf(x)\,\quad\text{ for }0\le t\le 1
$$
only when $a\le 0\,.$ Indeed, $t^2x^2+a\le tx^2+at$ implies $a\le 0$ just by taking the case $t=0\,.$

In general it follows from (1) that $f(0)\le tf(0)\,,\,\forall t\in[0,1]\,.$
So that

- $f(0)\le 0\,.$

The property (1) is equivalent to
$$\tag{2}
\frac{f(x)}{x}\quad\text{ being increasing on } (-\infty,0)\text{ and on }(0,+\infty)\,.
$$
Let $0<y<x<\infty\,.$ Then $t=y/x\in(0,1)$ and (1) implies
$$
f(y)=f(tx)\le tf(x)=\frac{y}{x}f(x)\,.
$$
Therefore $f(x)/x$ is increasing on $(0,+\infty)\,.$ Let $-\infty<y<x<0\,.$ Then $t=x/y\in(0,1)$ and (1) implies
$$
f(x)=f(ty)\le tf(y)=\frac{x}{y}f(y)\,.
$$
Since $x<0$ this implies
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}\color{red}{\ge}\frac{f(y)}{y}
$$
so that $f(x)/x$ is also increasing on $(-\infty,0)\,.$ Conversely, assume that (2) holds. If $x<0$ then for $0<t<1$ the point $y=tx$ is in $(x,0)\,.$ Then
$$
\frac{f(x)}{x}\le\frac{f(y)}{y}=\frac{f(tx)}{tx}\,.
$$
Because $x<0$ this implies
$$
f(tx)\le tf(x)\,.
$$
If $x>0$ then $y=tx$ is in $(0,x)$ and
$$
\frac{f(y)}{y}=\frac{f(tx)}{tx}\le\frac{f(x)}{x}
$$
which implies (1).

Comment: Doesn’t answer the question, does it? The OP asked about the *name* of this property.

Comment: I doesn't. I am more interested in properties than in names. Esp. when a comment conjectured that is has something to do with convex functons.

Answer (score 0):

Such functions are said to be **subhomogeneous**. There’s a pattern here. If you have a name xxx for functions that satisfy an equality, then the name sub-xxx is used for functions that satisfy a similar inequality. So ….
Linear —> sublinear.
Additive —> subadditive.
Homogeneous —> subhomogeneous.
And so on.

I wouldn’t say the name subhomogeneous is common, but it’s not unknown, and it’s meaning is easy to guess.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to this usage of "subhomogeneous"? It's a sensible term but I wasn't able to find it used for this property.

Comment: I just googled “subhomogeneous function”. There were numerous hits. Here is one: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X13001972

Comment: @bubba . According to this link a function $f(x)$ is *subhomogeneous* when $f(tx)\le tf(x)$ for all $t>1$. A function is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) (of degree one) when $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for all $t$. OP's property makes those requirements only for $0\le t\le  1$.